# Ext-GWT 3.0 Grid Mouse Events

Tags: gwt, grid, tooltip, gxt

I have a grid which gets populated from the database and works fine. Now I want to add a mouseover event to this grid and display a tooltip text which shows all the column values in multi-line fashion for the highlighted record. The business case here is that there are quite a few columns that are being displayed in the grid and the user would like to have a quick preview instead of horizontally scrolling all the way to the end, before selecting the record. Squeezing all these columns to fit into the screen is not a clean solution in this case.

I have tried looking through all the available methods in the GXT 3.0 API for Grid and GridView but couldn't find anything to get the highlighted records. There are a couple of events for MouseMove, MouseDown and MouseClick but none for MouseOver.

I tried various forums as well to find a solution but there doesn't seem to be one yet so thought it might be useful for others as well if I start this thread.

Please note that this issue is not related to Ext-JS. The version I am using is Ext-GWT 3.0.1.

Thanks

Answer (score 2):

`MouseMove` IS the one you want. It's only fired when the mouse is over the widget.

**Alternatively**, you can sink a DOM event to the widget by using:

```
DOM.sinkEvents(widget.getElement(), Event.ONMOUSEOVER);
```

in your widget's `constructor` or `onLoad` method, and then override the widget's onBrowserEvent:

```
@Override
public void onBrowserEvent(Event event){
final int eventType = DOM.eventGetType(event);
    if(eventType == Event.ONMOUSEOVER) {
        //DISPLAY THE INFO
    }
}
```

This is definitely harder than directly adding a handler but pretty customizable. You can choose either one.

BTW you might want to get the position of mouse by using:

```
mouseX = DOM.eventGetClientX(event);
mouseY = DOM.eventGetClientY(event);
```

Comment: I have a separate class for the grid which implements the IsWidget and returns the Grid in the overridden asWidget() implementation. I am able to add the sinkEvents in the constructor but unable to override the onBrowserEvent. The grid class contains only the constructor and the aswidget methods. The other issue is that even if I get it to override, is there an API call exposed which I can use to get the highlighted record in the grid e.g., getHighlightedItem or something similar

Comment: @user1847252 So you mean you dont have a base class for grid class? You should... but even if you dont, you just need to implement `EventListener` interface. Highlight record is easy as setting the `normal` and `hover` CSS, or you can add `MouseOver` and `MouseOut` handler. And no it does not interfare with other actions/handlers. All events in GWT/Browser are propagated.

Answer (score 1):

You could accomplish this by creating a custom Cell, and passing that to the grid's specific ColumnConfig.

With the custom Cell, you have access to all the events you would need.
Once you have access to the info you need, displaying it can be done in many ways. GXT provides a lot of solutions for this. Quicktips may be the way to go here though.

Comment: Thanks Jonathan for the reply.

Comment: Creating a custom cell would give me what is available in the highlighted cell and not the record. Is it possible to fetch the record object itself which will then allow me to retrieve all columns data in the record? If yes, then I can use a custom cell e.g., for the ID column and then take it from there

Comment: Of course you can. When you create your cell class, create a constructor which takes in your view (or more specifically, your store). You then store off this instance to a private final variable, then you can query the store for the record corresponding to the current model. Make sense?